# Error on Xcode 4.3.2 <Attempt to write a readonly database>

Tags: iphone, sqlite, xcode4.3

I am new on iphone programming..
I keep getting the error 
and I have no idea how to change the permission for SQLite

> Error while updating. attempt to write a readonly database

and the following is my coding

> NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"card" ofType:@"sqlite"];
> sqlite3_stmt *statement;
>
> if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
>
>   {
>   const char *query_stmt = "UPDATE card SET isActivate =?";
>
>     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
>
>           {
>
>                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
>
>          }
>
>  }
>
>  sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, 1);
>
>    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
>
>    {
>
>          NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
>
>     }
>
> sqlite3_finalize(statement);
> sqlite3_close(db);

Hope someone could help me because this really makes me feel frustrated..

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy your sql file to your cache directory in order to use it correctly.
Here's some of my code:

```
NSString *sqlFile = @"database.sql";
NSArray *cachePath= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cacheDir = [cachePathobjectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [cacheDirstringByAppendingPathComponent:sqlFile];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// Copy the database sql file from the resourcepath to the documentpath
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:sqlFile];
    NSError *error;
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"[Database:Error] %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya.. I have copied the database into my directory..
It can SELECT perfectly, but when comes to UPDATE, it just not working..

Comment: No you haven't copied it into your documents directory. Your opening the database directly from your bundle. This should be done from within your cache (or documents) directory. These are 2 different things. `NSCachesDirectory != NSBundle`

Comment: What basvk is saying is after you run the code he gave you, then replace your file path string with NSString * filePath = databasePath;

Comment: is this method only for sql?
I am using sqlite and it seems like not functioning

Comment: .sql or .sqlite are the same, matter of naming your extensions. But I think you're missing the big picture. Try any of the online tutorials (google is your friend): http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/ or http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: is it only NSObject can access to database?
all the sql things cannot work with ViewController?